# two-way PERMANOVA and violation of Multivariate homogeneity of groups dispersions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, vegan

I would like to perform a two-way PERMANOVA for my data (***n*** = 17; **factor 1** with 2 factor levels, **factor 2** with 3 factor levels and **20 continuous variables**) using the vegan package. In order to adequatly use a PERMANOVA, I have to check the assumption of multivariate homogeneity of groups dispersions:

```
> bd <- betadisper(vegdist(data), factor_1)
> permutest(bd)

Permutation test for homogeneity of multivariate dispersions
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Response: Distances
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq      F N.Perm Pr(>F)
Groups     1 0.006977 0.0069768 0.9529    999  0.447
Residuals 15 0.109828 0.0073218    


> bd <- betadisper(vegdist(data), factor_2)
Warning message:
In betadisper(vegdist(data), factor_2) :
  some squared distances are negative and changed to zero
> permutest(bd)

Permutation test for homogeneity of multivariate dispersions
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Response: Distances
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq      F N.Perm Pr(>F)  
Groups     2 0.036202 0.0181011 2.9745    999  0.033 *
Residuals 14 0.085196 0.0060855                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> ad <- adonis2(data~factor_1 * factor_2, permutations = 999, method="bray")
> ad
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

                                        Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)   
factor_1                                 1 0.069949 0.22920 5.3269  0.003 **
factor_2                                 2 0.058774 0.19258 2.2380  0.062 . 
factor_1:factor_2                        2 0.032022 0.10492 1.2193  0.351   
Residual                                11 0.144444 0.47329                 
Total                                   16 0.305189 1.00000                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, I am not sure if I have to use betadisper for factor 1 and 2 seperatly.
Moreover, I have the problem that the assumption of of multivariate homogeneity of groups dispersions is not met for factor 2. Therefore, what can I do in this situation?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See here for a discussion of using a modified F statistic to account for non-homogenous dispersion:
https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues/344

It includes some code to implement it, although I don't think it's incorporated into vegan yet.